# Use x if z equals true else use z

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need forLoop1 to use `y` if `z` equals 1 else use `x` and same for forLoop2 but reversed

my code:

```
for z in range(3):
    count=[0]*plys
    for y in range(len(game)): #forLoop1
        for x in range(len(game[y])): #forLoop2
            for i in range(plys):
                if game[y][x] == i+1:
                    count[i] += 1
        for i in range(plys):
            if count[i] >= 3:
                print("Player " + str(i+1) + " is the winner")
        count=[0]*plys
```

I tried something like this:

```
for y if z == 0 else x in range(len(game)):
```

and:

```
for (y if z == 0 else x) in range(len(game)):
```

But that didn't work

Any help would be greatly appreciated
and sorry if I'm bad at explaining it

Comment: the explanation is bit confusing, do you mean you want to use `for y in range(len(game))` if `z == 1` and if `z!=1` then `for x in range(len(game))`?

Answer (score 1):

The `... if ... else ...` conditional expression produces an *expression*, you can't use it to man-handle the `for` loop index variable names like that.

But you *can* do this:

```
for z in range(3):
    count=[0]*plys
    for k1 in range(len(game)): #forLoop1
        for k2 in range(len(game)): #forLoop2
            y, x = (k1, k2) if z == 1 else (k2, k1)
            for i in range(plys):
                if game[y][x] == i+1:
                    count[i] += 1
        for i in range(plys):
            if count[i] >= 3:
                print("Player " + str(i+1) + " is the winner")
        count=[0]*plys
```

However, it might be clearer if you just use a full `if... else` block:

```
if z == 1:
    y, x = k1, k2
else:
    y, x = k2, k1
```

Comment: After posted this I realized it's kind of a dumb question. Thanks thought

Comment: @ocboogie I wouldn't call your question _dumb_, per se, but it is a little unclear in its current state. And I guess it's a convoluted way of looking at the problem. Rather than thinking in terms of swapping the loop indices, you really want to swap the `game` list indices. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: BTW, we don't usually delete our own questions on SO after they've received an answer... unless the question is really bad and the answer is too. :) See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/4014959